# Undefined variable error for calling a object constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, undefined-variable

I have a class `ReadBugXML` in a folder called `code` and I added a `__init__.py` to make the code as a package. `main.py` and `code` are in the root folder. My main file looks like this.

```
import sys
from code import *

def main():
    bug_report = ReadBugXML('bugreports.xml')
    report, structure = bug_reports.read_bugs()

    print(report[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is how my code\ReadBugXML.py look like

```
import os

class ReadBugXML:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        curr_dir = os.getcwd()
        data_file_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'data', filename)
        try:
            self.bug_file = open(data_file_path, encoding='utf8')
        except IOError:
            print('The file is missing!')

    def read_bugs(self):
       # read the xml and return a list
```

I have tried different import statements but didn't work out.

I expected that the object will be created. But it doesn't create any. I have tested the code within the ReadBugXML.py by creating an object and calling the function. It did work. But calling in the main seems to be the problem. I don't know how to fix the import for user-defined classes.

Instead, I am getting a pylint error 'Undefined variable ReadBugXML' in VSCode. Running the main file gives NameError: name ReadBugXML is not defined.

Note: I am using VSCode (win 10) as an editor and python 3.6 is the interpreter.

Comment: Can you show the code for `ReadBugXML` and `__init__.py`?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the code positioning.

Comment: I think you need `from .code import *` (notice the dot in front of `code`) for importing from a local folder.

Comment: @clockelliptic My `__init__.py is empty

Comment: you need to do something to the effect of `from code.ReadBugXML import *`, not, by convention, module name should be lower-case, so `readbugxml.py`. Also note, using starred imports here is considered bad practice.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Thanks pointing that out. I just fixed my code as you said and now it works. Now my import statements are like `from code.read_bug_xml import ReadBugXML`. So every time I have a class in a different file in `code` it needs to be imported like this. Is there a different best practice to import user-defined classes in main(). Feels like I am doing some silly programming.

Comment: @akalanka this is what `__init__.py` is for, import all the classes you want to be able to import from `code`, **it is that module**. Also, generally in Python, you don't do one class per file as you might in Java. So, you don't have a bunch of files with the same name as a single class in them. Module group related pieces of code (functions, classes) into a single namespace. It *sounds* like you probably just want a single python file, `code.py` with your class in there (and any other related classes)